How to Retrieve and Compare All Settings and Overrides for a Specific Table in PostgreSQL (version 12)?
I am working with a PostgreSQL 12 database and currently investigating a table (table_name in schema schema_name) that has accumulated a significant number of dead tuples. To address this, I am examining both the PostgreSQL system-wide settings and any overrides that might be applied specifically to this table, with a particular focus on autovacuum settings.
What are the queries I can use to find out all the settings that applies to the table, including any overrides, in a glance?

I wrote a PL/pgSQL function that fetches a comprehensive list of all relevant settings from pg_settings, displays whether each setting is overridden in the table's reloptions, and shows both the default and overridden values if applicable. Here’s how the function is structured:
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_all_settings_with_overrides(schema_name TEXT, table_name TEXT)
    RETURNS TABLE(setting_name TEXT, is_overridden BOOLEAN, default_value TEXT, table_value TEXT) AS $$
DECLARE
    -- Variables for option name and value from reloptions.
    option_name TEXT;
    option_value TEXT;
    -- Record to hold settings data.
    setting_record RECORD;
    -- Variables for each option.
    each_option TEXT;
BEGIN
    -- Loop through all settings relevant to autovacuum or other categories.
    FOR setting_record IN SELECT * FROM pg_settings LOOP
            option_value := NULL; -- Reset the option_value for each setting.

            -- Perform a lateral join to unnest the reloptions for the specified table.
            SELECT INTO option_name, option_value split_part(option, '=', 1), split_part(option, '=', 2)
            FROM pg_class, LATERAL unnest(coalesce(reloptions, ARRAY[''])) as option
            WHERE relname = table_name AND relnamespace = (SELECT oid FROM pg_namespace WHERE nspname = schema_name)
              AND option LIKE setting_record.name || '=%';

            -- Return the setting with indication if it is overridden.
            RETURN QUERY SELECT setting_record.name, (option_value IS NOT NULL AND option_value != setting_record.setting) AS is_overridden, setting_record.setting, option_value;
        END LOOP;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

While this function works, I am wondering if there is a more straightforward or efficient way to achieve the same result without having to resort to a custom function. Are there built-in tools or simpler methods in PostgreSQL that I might have overlooked? I’m looking for any advice that could streamline this process or improve the clarity of the output, making it easier to diagnose and potentially rectify the autovacuum behavior for this problematic table.
Thank you in advance for your insights!
